# How to use another network adapter over windows server RRAS VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access, windows-server, rras

I've run and started a VPN server on Windows Server 2016 using RRAS which is now enable to connect my clients to internet using the server's IP but the problem is that I want my clients to be able to use another Ethernet on my server too that is connected to the local network.

To explain better, I have a valid IP address by which my clients connect to my server over VPN and another adapter with IP range of 10.X.X.X that is connected to my office network.

What should I do to enable my remote clients to access the websites hosted on the local networks?

P.S. I followed [this guide](https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-with-windows-server/) to run the VPN server step by step.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For this type of question, perhaps ServerFault might be a more appropriate place to ask this?  SO is a programming site.

Comment: Hi. I'm a programmer myself and tbh it's the first time I hear of ServerFault. Can my question stay here please? Kinda think I'm going to get better results here after all